# Printing ancestry report to specific ancestor

Tags: gedcom

I am trying to print out an ancestry report to one specific ancestor (mainly as a worksheet for a couple membership applications).  All I've ever been able to find are things like "fan" reports, or long lists of EVERYONE in each generation.  I want to get rid of all the side relations, children, parents/grandparents/etc that aren't part of that specific line.  Does anyone even make such a thing?  I already have a file from Family Tree Maker 7, exported to GEDCOM format.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackExchange! What program are you using to print your report? Programs like Family Historian often have an "Individual Summary Report" which only looks at one of your gedcom entries.

Comment: Are you looking for a report that lists you and each of your direct ancestors that lead to a specific direct ancestor, and nobody else?  If you included a rough picture of what you are after it may help to attract potential answerers.

Comment: Let's just say we're going back just four generations, to your paternal grandmother's maternal grandfather.  So you're going to have a line like:

You -- Your Father -- His Mother (your grandmother) -- Her Mother (your great-grandmother) -- Her Father (your great-great grandfather). (this formats better OFF of StackExchange).   

So your chart consists of just five people, including yourself (I'm dealing with more than 4 here, so the number of extra people doubles each generation).

I was trying this with Family Tree Maker v7.0 (yes, that old) and Gramps (the most recent version).

Comment: @jelabarre, are you open to trying different software? I have an answer, but it requires a different program that claims to be able to import from FTM.

Comment: Odd, I thought I had already posted a reply to this, but apparently not (and I can't format to multiple lines either).  As long as any other software can be run under Linux I'm OK (running through Wine/Crossover is fine).